# How to use a shell variable inside sed's s command?

Tags: shell, sed, quoting, variable

we know that we can get the value of a variable using $ sign:

```
x=3
echo $x
3
```

Is there other ways that we can use to get the value without using $ sign.

I'm asking this because $ sign is a special character to `sed`, and I get `sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated s' command` error when trying to do this:

```
A=25 #lineNumber
destStr="192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4"
sed ""$A"s/Allow from .*/Allow from $destStr/" -i test2
```

and it prints the string `destStr`(not the value) when I use the escape character `\`:

```
sed ""$A"s/Allow from .*/Allow from \$destStr/" -i test2
```

using `echo` instead of `sed`:

```
25s/Allow from .*/Allow from  192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
/ -i test2
```

Comment: Which shell are you using? Your first version works just fine for me using `bash`.

Comment: @celtschk, I'm using `bash` too.

Comment: Do you get the error with *exactly* the values you've given? Especially: Does `destStr` have the literal value `string`?

Comment: @celtschk,No see Edits

Comment: What is the output if you replace `sed` with `echo` (but leave the arguments unchanged)?

Comment: @celtschk,see Updates,so I guess my problem was : `the value contains "\n"`.

Comment: So I get that you did *not* set `destStr` with the command above, but got it from somewhere else, and whereever you got it from inserted *newline* characters in between. That's your real problem (it is completely unrelated to the dollar sign), and that's also why your `echo` solution works: `echo` replaces that line feed with a simple space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the final edits revealed, the problem is unrelated to the dollar sign, but is caused by the content of `deststr`, which is not `192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4` but rather two lines, one containing only `192.168.1.3` and the other containing only `192.168.1.4`, both lines bveing terminated with a newline character. That is, the actual command after variable replacement is:

```
sed "25s/Allow from .*/Allow from  192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
/" -i test2
```

Now `sed` interprets its command line by line, and thus the first command it tries to interpret is:

```
25s/Allow from .*/Allow from  192.168.1.3
```

which clearly is an unterminated `s` command, and thus reported by `sed` as such.

Now the solution you found, using `echo`, works because

```
echo $var
```

calls echo with *two* arguments (because the whitespace is not quoted, it is interpreted as argument delimiter), the first one being `192.168.1.3` and the second one being `192.168.1.4`; both are forms that are not interpreted further by the shell.

Now `echo` just outputs its (non-option) arguments separated by a space, therefore you now get as command line:

```
sed "25s/Allow from .*/Allow from  192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4/" -i test2
```

as intended.

Note however that for command substitution, instead of backticks you should use `$()` whereever possible, since it's too easy to get backticks wrong. Therefore the follwing does what you want:

```
sed "$A s/Allow from .*/Allow from $(echo $destStr)/" -i test2
```

Note that I also took advantage of the fact that `sed` allows a space between address and command, to simplify the quoting. In situations where such an extra space is not possible, you can also use the following syntax:

```
sed "${A}s/Allow from .*/Allow from $(echo $destStr)/" -i test2
```

Also note that this relies on the fact that the non-space characters in `destStr` are interpreted neither by the shell, nor by `sed` if occurring in the replacement string.

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to solve my problem using `echo` with ``:

```
sed ""$A"s/Allow from .*/Allow from `echo $destStr`/" -i test2
```

but I'm still want to know if there are other ways to get the value without using $ sign.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it within the script:

```bash
sed -e "${A}s/Allow from .*/Allow from ${destStr}/" -i test2
```

Using `${variable}` let the bash interpret `${variable}s/...` like you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to actually answer the stated question: "Is there other ways that we can use to get the value without using $ sign."

This isn't in the context of your use case, but you could do something like this:

```
$SOME_VAR="some value or something"
f() { echo ${!1}; }
some_command `f "SOME_VAR"`
```

You could use this to avoid using $ in the argument list for sed.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
sed $A's/Allow from .*/Allow from '$destStr'/' -i test2
```

assuming destStr have no white.

or

```
echo $A"s/Allow from .*/Allow from $destStr/" | sed -f - -i test2
```

the second form allow white.

Comment: it didn't work too, both ways didn't work